# How many solutions are there in the following equation over the natural numbers if $x_1+x_2+x_3>x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many solutions are there in the following equation over the natural numbers such that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7=30$ if $x_1+x_2+x_3>x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7$  ?

I made up a combinatorics question in my mind  , but i stuck in it. What i tried is :

Firstly , i wanted to use symmetry property but , it has odd number of variables . Hence ,i could not do anything.

Secondly , i thought about whether generating functions can be used or not , but i stuck in writing the desired generating formula for it.

So , i  hope to find nice approaches to my question.

$NOTE=$Natural numbers start with zero.

Comment: @BrianMScott last line implies that $0\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using stars and bars you can write the number of solution as
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{14}\binom{i+3}3\binom {30-i+2}2,
$$
where the first factor counts the number of solutions to the equation $x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7=i $ and the second one those of $x_1+x_2+x_3=30-i $.

Comment: thanks for your answer , it is correct but , i hope to find easier way than you did.Because , for large numbers , this solution will be cumbersome process. By the way , i glad to see you again:) +1

Comment: @Bulbasaur Have you found an easier way?

Comment: I think that an elegant generating function can be found to get rid of cumbersome process and I appreciate your work for me. By the way , i forgot  this question. I  guess the new answer wont be come. If I can find nice way , i will say you. Thanks for your work.At last , lets forget the past bad experience between us. I appreciate your knowledge and good wills. Have a nice day..